# Advantages / Drawbacks of Spring Async vs. Websocket

Tags: spring, asynchronous, websocket, spring-websocket

What are the main differences, advantages and drawbacks of using Spring @Async and Spring Websockets for long background tasks like database queries? Are both equally used or are there special cases where one of them fits better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relatively infrequent long background tasks are cases for `@Async`. Websocket is more appropriate for intensive communication between client and server like chat clients.

From the Spring docu:

> The best fit for WebSocket is in web applications where the client and
>   server need to exchange events at high frequency and with low latency.
>   Prime candidates include, but are not limited to, applications in
>   finance, games, collaboration, and others. Such applications are both
>   very sensitive to time delays and also need to exchange a wide variety
>   of messages at a high frequency.
>
> For other application types, however, this may not be the case. For example, a news or social feed that shows breaking news as it
>   becomes available may be perfectly okay with simple polling once every
>   few minutes. Here latency is important, but it is acceptable if the
>   news takes a few minutes to appear.
>
> Even in cases where latency is crucial, if the volume of messages is relatively low (e.g. monitoring network failures) the use of long
>   polling should be considered as a relatively simple alternative that
>   works reliably and is comparable in terms of efficiency (again
>   assuming the volume of messages is relatively low).

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've used websockets in a project already, but according to your answer / spring doc, @Async would be more appropriate. In the application, I currently use a stomp client via javascript to update my JSP when the result has finished. What would I typically use for this with @Async? JMS?

Comment: Spring Async hooks into Servlet 3 proprietary async support, so you do NOT need to add another technology for asynchronous task handling to the equation, i.e. JMS. Simply annotate your handler method with Async and make it return Callable or DeferredResult to prepare your response once asynchronous processing is done.